# Create array of start and end datetimes from two datetime variables

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have a start and end DateTime object and want to iterate over them to get an array of start and end per day. To iterate over it I wrote this function:

```
public function getDatesBetweenTwoDates($start = null, $end = null)
{
    return iterator_to_array(new \DatePeriod($start, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $end));
}
```

However, this function returns an array like this and does not support times:

```
['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', ...]
```

What I need is something like this:

Input:

```
$start = new DateTime("2017-10-01 10:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("2017-10-03 19:00:00");
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        'start' => '2017-10-01 10:00:00',
        'end' => '2017-10-01 23:59:59'
    ],
    [
        'start' => '2017-10-02 00:00:00',
        'end' => '2017-10-02 23:59:59'
    ],
    [
        'start' => '2017-10-03 00:00:00',
        'end' => '2017-10-03 19:00:00'
    ],
]
```

Any hint or help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you will need to iterate over your array and re-create the array of dates with the new format

```
$start = new DateTime("2017-10-01 10:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("2017-10-03 19:00:00");

$datesArray = iterator_to_array(new \DatePeriod($start, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $end));

array_walk($datesArray, function ($value, $key) use (&$dates, $start, $end) {

    $dates[$key]['start'] = (
        ($key == 0) ? $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : $value->setTime(00, 0, 00)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );

    $endDate = $value->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    if ($endDate->getTimestamp() > $end->getTimestamp()) {
        $endDate = $end;
    }

    $dates[$key]['end'] = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


});
print_r($dates);
```

this will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-10-01 10:00:00
            [end] => 2017-10-01 23:59:59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-10-02 00:00:00
            [end] => 2017-10-02 23:59:59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-10-03 00:00:00
            [end] => 2017-10-03 19:00:00
        )

)
```

live sample : https://3v4l.org/UnDcA

**Note :** as you can see at 3v4l that you will get different/wrong output if you will use HHVM.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I wanted!

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
<?php
 $start = "start_date";
 $end = "end_date";
 $date = array("start"=>$start, "end"=>$end);
 $dates = array();
 array_push($dates, $date);
 print_r($dates);
?>
```